# QTrayIcon doesn't show on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to add System Tray Icon to my QT application. Code works fine on Windows 7 to Windows 10 but the tray icon doesn't show up on CentOS 7. Application is working because it's getting also external signals and shows messages. Code bellow:

```
createTrayIcon();
trayIcon->show();
```

And function:

```
void Window::createTrayIcon()
{
    trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
    trayIconMenu->addAction(logiAction);
    trayIconMenu->addAction(managerAction);
    trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);

    trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
    trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(QString(":/resources/klatki/app.jpg")));

}
```

Comment: Look at CentOS [forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57510). It seems like your case.

Comment: I have all of following extensions installed and enabled in version 3.26.2-3.el7 so it shouldn't been a case.

Comment: Which DE you have? Because if that's Gnome-based DE, you have to make additional steps to show your icon on the tray.

Comment: It is GNOME version 3.22.2

Comment: @PPM Even if additional add-ons are installed that does not mean that it solves unfortunately, Qt currently has several bugs regarding wayland, which is what the latest gnome versions use. :-(

Comment: I found error of functions :   `QApplication::setApplicationName();
    QApplication::setOrganizationName("");
    QApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0");` were set before constructor of window where tray icon was set. It wasn't problem on Windows as I said.

Comment: Unfortunately after deployment, and running on the other system tray icon doesn't showed. I get `QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible - No Icon Set ` The problem occurs when I'm using static linked libraries from installation folder. When I'm using dynamic linking it's ok, but it's not my goal.